# Singular value decomposition of product involving orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose that $D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is orthogonal, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ only has elements on the main diagonal, and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal, with $n < m$.
Now consider
$$
A=U\Sigma V^T.
$$
This reminds me of an SVD for A, but I am not sure if it is actually its SVD.

I know that $U\Sigma$ and $U\Sigma V^T$ have the same singular values, since

$$U\Sigma V^T V \Sigma^T U^T = U\Sigma \Sigma^T U^T$$

but can I say more on the singular values of $U \Sigma$?

Comment: It is not clear why you believe that the determinant equation you have written tells us anything about the singular values.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, you are right. I made a mess in my head. I was trying to use the fact that the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist diagonal matrices $D,\Sigma_+$ (with $D$ square) such that $\Sigma = D\Sigma_+$, where the diagonal entries of $D$ are all $\pm 1$ and the diagonal entries of $\Sigma_+$ are non-negative.  It follows that
$$
A = (UD) \Sigma_+D^T
$$
is a singular value decomposition.   So, we see that the singular values of $A$ are the entries of $\Sigma_+$, which are the the absolute values of the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ok so if $\Sigma$ already only has positive values, then the singular values of $A$ are the same as the ones of $\Sigma$.

Comment: @Omega Yes. In general, if $U \Sigma V^T$ is an SVD, then the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ are the singular values, and these values are also the singular values of $\Sigma$.

Comment: So if we have a product of the above form we can be sure that it is "a" singular value decomposition? Are there more SVD decompositions if one requests that the singular values are ordered decreasingly?

Comment: @Omega Technically you're right; I didn't account for the fact that in an SVD the singular values should be decreasing along the diagonal, so $U \Sigma_+ V^T$ might not be an SVD. That said, it is indeed true that if $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with non-negative entries, then the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ (whichever order they appear in) are the singular values of $A$.

Comment: @Omega And in general, it is indeed true that the singular value decomposition is non-unique. In particular, if $P,Q$ are orthogonal matrices with $P\Sigma Q = \Sigma$, then we have
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T \implies A = (U P) \Sigma (VQ)^T
$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you! You really helped me understanding more!